# (facebook like app) show post algorithm design

Tags: algorithm, meteor, design-patterns, architecture

I making a mobile app similar to facebook as a college project. Problem I am facing is say if I have 25 users and 24 users posted something on the site of which user1 made the first post. Now say the 25th user logs in after two days. Initially I was showing the feeds in FIFO order. But if I keep using FIFO, 25th user wont be able to see the last post unless he has undergone all the previous posts first. Same situation in LIFO. If we scale up the app, the problem statement would be huge as there would be some feeds which will never be seen. So how do I tackle this?

I thought of distributing users into groups and show the feeds within the groups first, and then to the neighbouring group and so on.

PS: I am using meteorjs for building the app.

So I have distributed the users into groups. I have attached a tag with every feed saying user from which group posted it. 
Now I sort the feeds according to date-time at which they were created. Then I group them according to their user groups. Then I sort the feeds according to the no.of views (sorting within the group only).

Now I keep the sorted data as a list. To show the feeds to the user, I am trying to use trees. Say a user belonging to group 4 logs in. So I would use the group 4 data as node and create a binary tree. Then I would show all the feeds in the head first, then do a bfs traversal to show the feeds on the leaves.

Is there any other better method to make sure that every feed is seen atleast once by any user

Comment: What I thought was, say we have 100users. I will distribute them in a four groups of 25each. Let the groups be g1, g2, g3, g4. If any user belonging to g1 makes a post, then all the users of g1 should see the post first, and then the post should move to g2, then to g3 and so on. But I am not sure if this is a realistic solution and if thic could be done in meteorjs.

Comment: In my opinion, this is more a design question rather than an algorithm one. It is really general and I would suggest you to ask something more specific then that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So what I could think of is that you can divide the users into groups firstly. Then show the feeds from the same group. But show only new feeds here. Then show the feeds from neighbouring groups and move on. Then show the old feeds in the same manner.